# C# PictureBox rotate vertical

Tags: c#, alignment, picturebox, flip

i have create a picture box that shows an image while values changes.I want to show from bottom to top.
The only way that i found is from left to right and from top to bottom

this is the code that i use now from Top to Bottom

```
//suspbar1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.);
suspbar1.Height = 0;
suspbar1.Height = suspbar1.Height + 1;
suspbar1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(SuspensionTravel0 * 1000 / 1.55);
```

*suspbar1 is my picturebox.

Comment: Look again! RotateFlip has what you want. That is, if I understand you right. Not sure about that, though.. I'm sure though that I don't understand your code!

Comment: i use only this line of the code.
`suspbar1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(SuspensionTravel0 * 1000 / 1.55);`
So, suspbar1 is my picurebox as i told and i have an image on it.
suspbar1 dimensions is width:30 , length :90 , so is vertical.
with this code background image appears and disappears from TOP to BOTTOM as the value change.(Is the move of a car suspension).
I want to make it appears and disappears from BOTTOM to TOP.
Using RotateFlip , not work because change the image on the picturebox.I want to flip the picturebox not the image if it is possible.

Comment: Controls can't be rotated, only moved inside other controls or on the form. I'm afraid I still don't know what you want.

Comment: imaging that we have a vertical bar....this bar is an image into picturebox...this image appears according a value....value is a number from 0 - 145 (susppension travel of a car).With this code 
`suspbar1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(SuspensionTravel0 * 1000 / 1.55);`
i have the view effect that i want.
BUT!...with Height image appears from TOP of PictureBox to BOTTOM.I want to appears from BOTTOM to TOP....

Comment: You keep repeating the same desription. Maybe I don't understand because your whole approach is fundamentally wrong.. Keeping in  line with your assumed approach you would maybe have to change both Height and Top of the PictureBox. But you ought to start by getting the basics right. What SizeMode is the PBox in? And how large are Image and PBox? - Also: There seems to be no rotation involved at all. If that is so, please remove the term from Tag and Title!